# Saving images to db

Tags: c#, image, stream, storage, alphablending

I can save an image to the database streaming it to a byte array using the below code, but when it comes back out it has lost the alpha blending around the image and shows a blocky blue border.

```
image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
```

How can I get the original picture back out?

Comment: It would help to know what you're doing with the image when you're trying to retrieve it. I have several different pieces of code to retrieve images from a db depending on the use of the image once you get it back.

Comment: Thanks Justin,
I'm either displaying it into a listview (thumbnail) with a large number of other images.
The second part is exporting it back to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely have to save it as a byte array... I have heard of several issues with trying to do this. What about saving the path and other image information so your application can just get it out of a directory...

Comment: Thanks J,
I thought about saving path's but I wanted to embed the images (all tiny, 32KB max) in the db for portability purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a specific `ImageFormat`, e.g.:

```
image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
```